# Delcaración textual de variables con y sin comillas en JS

Tags: javascript, variables

Me surgió una duda mientras me introduzco en JavaScript, de hecho, comencé antes de ayer (ya he prácticado algunos meses HTML y CSS).

Estoy repasando variables y asignación, pero por error declaré una variable de texto sin comillas como sale aquí abajo y en el navegador se muestra este error: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: prueba is not defined  http://127.0.0.1:5500/java.js:1"*

```
let mensaje = prueba;
alert(mensaje);
```

Sin embargo, cuando asigno las comillas, se muestra correctamente (el código de abajo). Tengo algunas ideas, pero quisiera una opinión de más experiencia sobre el motivo que genera el error y por qué no pasa lo mismo con caracteres numéricos . De antemano, muchas gracias.

```
let mensaje = "prueba";
alert(mensaje);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nota: Voy a tratar de no enredar mucho la explicación

**1) Tipos de datos**
En javascript tienes 2 tipos de datos que son las más usados

- String (Texto)
- Number (numerico) -> Este se divide en 2

  - int (entero)
  - float (decimales)

En otros lenguajes debes declarar el tipo de variable, en javascript no es necesario.

**2) Declaración de variables**

Las variables se declaran usando las palabras var o let, ejemplo:

- var mensaje;
- let prueba;

**3) Asignación de variables**

La razón de ser de las variables es que tu almacenes información en ellas, para ello usas la igualdad

- var mensaje ="hola";
- var numero = 2;

Como podrás ver los textos se asignan con comillas (simples o dobles) y los números sin ninguna comillas. De esta manera Javascript entiende que tipo de dato le estas ingresando.

Por ejemplo, declarmos 3 variables

- var n1 = 1;
- var n2 = 2;
- var n3 = "3"

ojo con la última que la declare como texto

- n1+n2=3
- n1+n3=13

En el primer caso suma sin problema. En el segundo lo que hace es concatenar, es decir escribir un 1 seguido de un 3. Por esto es importante identificar el tipo de dato (entre otras muchísimas razones)

** Respondiendo a tus ejemplos**

```
let mensaje = "prueba";
alert(mensaje);
```

Esto funciona porque hiciste todo bien, asignaste a mensaje el texto "prueba", en cambio:

```
let mensaje = prueba;
alert(mensaje);
```

Esto no funciona porque prueba no ha sido asignado, ahora si haces esto:

```
let prueba;
let mensaje = prueba;
alert(mensaje);
```

Si funciona, pero la alerta arroja "undefined", porque la variable prueba no ha sido definida, ahora la definimos:

```
let prueba="hola";
let mensaje = prueba;
alert(mensaje);
```

Y el mensaje arroja hola. Fija lo que se hizo:

- Declare una variable cuyo contenido es "hola"
- declare otra variable, cuyo contenido es el contenido de prueba, es decir "hola"

No sé si toda esta chachara responde en algo tus dudas, espero que si.

Answer (score 2):

Mi explicación

```
let mensaje = "prueba"
alert(mensaje)
```

Le estas asignando a la variable `mensaje` el valor **"prueba"** o sea un cadena como tambien podrias hacerlo con numeros.

Ejemplo:

```
let mensaje = 1 //Aqui la variable mensaje se declara como tipo int ya que le pase un numero
alert(mensaje)



let mensaje = "1" //Aqui la variable mensaje se declara como tipo string ya que le pase un numero PERO de tipo string entre **""**
alert(mensaje)
```

Entonces, si lo representas como lo siguiente

```
let mensaje = prueba
alert(mensaje)
```

Estas diciendo que a la varible `mensaje` le asignas la variable `prueba` sin embargo la variable prueba no esta declarada en ninguna parte.

Ya si fuese asi:

```
let prueba = "Soy el valor de otra variable"

let mensaje = prueba
alert(mensaje)
```

Aquí estas asignando la variable `prueba` a la variable `mensaje` o sea que le estas pasando el valor contenido en la variable `prueba` y además la variable si existe.